# Asp.net failed validators counter

Tags: c#, asp.net

I wanna perform the function:

```
int counter = 0;
    foreach (IValidator iv in this.Validators.Cast<IValidator>().Where(v => !v.IsValid).ToList())
    {
        counter++;
    }
    lblError.Text = "<i class='fas fa-times-circle redI'></i> You Have " + counter + " Errors";
```

and I can't figure out how to run it every time the page validates... is it possible? help is appreciated

Comment: You will have to have an event listener such as onPageValidation..
In JS this is usually done by listening to form.onSubmit()

Answer (score 0):

Any time you find yourself using an iterator, you could probably refactor with LINQ. This doesn't mean it's a good idea `always` but most of the time it leads to better readable code.

Try this:
`var violationCount = Validators.Cast<IValidator>().Count(validationRes => !validationRes.isValid);`

Comment: Scratch that last comment, tried adding this js function with an event listener (never used it before so I hope I'm not using it wrong):

      `document.getElementById("form1").addEventListener('submit', functSubmit);
    function functSubmit() {
        __doPostBack('btnCheck', 'OnClick');
    }`
and added an invisible button which goes as follows:

      `<asp:Button ID="btnCheck" class="btn btn-primary" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" style="background: transparent; border: none !important; font-size:0;" OnClick="cvCount_ServerValidate" />`

Doesnt work, just submits..

Comment: code behind now goes as follows:

    `protected void cvCount_ServerValidate(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var count = this.Validators.Cast<IValidator>().Count(v => !v.IsValid);
        lblError.Text = "<i class='fas fa-times-circle redI'></i> You Have " + count + " Errors";
        
    }`

But Like I said in the last comment, I dont know how to use event listeners and all it does is submit without checking and fails

Comment: It's a little tricky mixing razor and js due to sharing state. Generally a way to do this, is to share state from backend to frontend. The way this is achieved is by using a model binding like this:

https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/model-binding
Store your validation state inside model state, you should be able to evaluate state inside form submission.

However, I would recommend you refactor for a simpler mechanism. 
Just use frontend validation with JQuery Validate (maintain backend validation for protection) but use frontend validation for presentation & good UX